# How to run JUPYTERLAB from inside Pycharm (either internally in a captive window, or in an external browser)?

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter-lab

I cannot find instructions for how to configure Pycharm to run JUPYTERLAB Client from inside Pycharm.

JupyterLab Client will eventually replace Jupyter Classic Notebook as the default development and runtime platform.

How do I configure JupyterLab to run as the default Jupyter Client from within Pycharm?

What I tried:

0. I searched all over the PyCharm Forums and Google universe and found nothing about JupyterLab running in PyCharm.
1. Searched all menus looking for JupyterLab.
2. Installed JupyterLab within a conda environment using PyCharm.
3. Opened PyCharm "Settings" menu,
4. Selected "Languages and Frameworks"
5. Selected "Jupyter... Jupyter Server"
6. Selected "Managed Server"
7. Selected "Python 3.9 (base) c:\users\programdata\anaconda3\pythonw.exe"
8. Clicked "Okay"
9. Clicked "Run in External Browser"
10. ... the external browser opened up Firefox (my default browser)

BUT IT IS RUNNING JUPYTER CLASSIC NOTEBOOK, which is not what I need.

How do I configure PyCharm to start JupyterLab from within PyCharm??

It would be best if it could be run internally to PyCharm and externally in the default browser (or a selected browser).

It is greatly preferred to run JupyterLab OUTSIDE PyCharm because the styling is "tighter" and it looks and works better.

Does anyone know exactly how to configure PyCharm to leverage JupyterLab?

Perhaps this requirement just too new for JetBrains to support JupyterLab Client?

Any instructions on how to do this are welcome (or technical reasons why it is blocked or not working). If there is a non-technical reason why this is not possible, i.e., marketing or product management does not want to do it, please let the user community know, so that we can politely hammer PyCharm product managers and marketing managers.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem. Basically just replace `notebook` with `lab`, like in the snapshot below:-

[image]